# How To Sniff Modem's Traffic

Tags: networking, modem, wireshark, sniffing

Every time my Modem (Sagem F@ST 3284, which is also a router) reboots it sends a request to the ISP with the current OS version. If it's not updated it will download the firmware from the ISP and perform a silent system update.

I want to get the firmware file of the Modem but the ISP is not willing to supply it. As far as I know the only way is to monitor the traffic of the Modem but I have no idea how to do it.

Can it be done with Wireshark somehow?

Comment: It would help if you said what technology your modem is for: DSL? DOCSIS? LTE?… POTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark will only detect internal network traffic, while the communication
of the router with the ISP is done on another unconnected network.

You would need specialized hardware for sniffing that communication,
and then you would need to unravel the communication protocol they are
using, which is really too much work.

Your ISP uses either standard router and firmware, or has modified one.

In the first case, the firmware name and version will be indicated in the
router's maintenance screen, and you can search for it on the Internet.

Even in the second case, it might still be possible to find the named
firmware on the Internet.

If you wish for help, add these details to your post.

Comment: Thanks! It has a modified firmware. It is basically Sagem F@ST 3284. So I guess it's impossible?

Comment: This is a pretty weird modem. I haven't found any information for it on the website of `sagemcom.com`, no manual and no firmware downloads. No alternate firmware by both dd-wrt and openwrt. Nobody seems to bother with it. Your only hope might be to search for a backup option in the maintenance page (I think at `192.168.1.1`), but verify that it saves the firmware and not just the configuration. You might sneakily call your ISP Support, say you suspect a problem which a router reset haven't fixed (better know how), and ask if they can help you reinstall the firmware.

Comment: thanks! it is indeed pretty weird modem. I already tried the backup option. it saves a .bin file. I tried to open it in binwalk but it wan't able to analyze it.it probably contains all the settings encrypted... But I can't know the key of the encryption without having the firmware. I might try contacting the ISP. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @user3611091 to read the .bin file you need to xor every byte with 0x80. Hint: there's likely a user named expert that has access to extra settings.